# addition game fence-post issue, addition sign shows before the equation

Tags: java

I am making an addition game but the only problem I have is that the addition sign keeps showing up before the problem even though there is no number in front of it. What is the easiest way to fix this?

```
  package addgame;
  import java.util.Random;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class AddingGame {
private static Scanner console;

public static void main (String[]args) {
System.out.println("We are going to play an adding game, you have 3 tries. Type your answer.");
equation(); 
}   
public static void equation() {
    int tries = 5;
    int points=0;
    Random rand = new Random ();
    while (tries>=3) {
    int totalnums = rand.nextInt(4)+1;
    int sumAns=0;
    for (int i=1; i<=totalnums+1;i++) {
    int nums= rand.nextInt(10)+1;
    System.out.print(" + "+nums ); 
    sumAns+=nums;
}
    System.out.print(" = ");
    console = new Scanner (System.in);
    int ans = console.nextInt();
    if(ans!=sumAns) {
        tries--;
    }
    else if(tries>=3) {
    points++;   
    }
    if(tries<3) {
            System.out.println("Game Over...");
            System.out.println("Points="+points+"\nBetter luck next time!");

        }
    }

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues here beyond what you posted.

First of all, don't use tries = 5 when they only have 3 tries. This is unclear. What if you or someone else has to look over this program at a later date? Would you know what "tries = 5" meant?

If you instead say something like

```
int triesLeft = 3;
```

There is far less ambiguity. And by starting on 3, your while statement is also more straightforward.

```
while (triesLeft > 0) {
```

Similarly, it is a bit unclear how many numbers you want to add. As you've noticed, it would be problematic in an addition game if the number of numbers you were adding was 0 or 1. Your solution does work. However, if you instead did this... (I've included one possible solution to your question in this block of code as well.)

```
int numberOfAddends = rand.nextInt(4)+2;  //This assumes the maximum number of numbers you want to add is 5 (i.e. 3 + 2), and the minimum number is 2.
int sumAns = rand.nextInt(10)+1;  //Now note these two lines.
System.out.print(sumAns); //this will make sure the first number is printed before the + sign

for (int i=1; i < numberOfAddends;i++) { 
    //the inside of this for loop can stay the same.
}
```

Notice that it is easier to tell what is going on now. It might be worthwhile considering if there are any ways you could make it even clearer.

Past this point, it's really just small things with your code.

```
while(triesLeft > 0) {
    .
    .
    .
    if(ans!=sumAns) {
        tries--;
    }
    else {  //the check you specified was only ever reachable when the condition you were checking is true. What you wrote was equivalent to else if (true). 
    points++;   
    }
}
System.out.println("Game Over..."); //You don't need a check for this when it is placed outside the while loop. 
System.out.println("Points="+points+"\nBetter luck next time!");
```